# How to create x amount of image box in html javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I've a simple project where users could upload some images. Now I need to create `x` amount `<img/>` boxes, where `x` contains the amount of photos that user have saved in my server.

I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me how to create x amount of image boxes in html.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I think you didn't read my question title

Comment: And what have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a place where you get people do the work for you, but to help you with your coding problems.

Comment: I haven't tried anything cause I don't know where to start with

Comment: @MaxArt FYI: arnabkaycee answered it if you didn't know how it's done. thanks

Comment: If you don't know where to start, first you have to read some beginner's guides just to know what you're doing. And even before posting here you should read some posting guide lines to avoid bothering other users with clueless questions. To begin with, you *have* to try by yourself first and only then report your attempts in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to create tags at runtime:

Example:

```js
$(function(){
  var x = 10;
  for(var i=0; i<x; i++){
    $('body').append('<img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/firey-orange-jelly-icons-symbols-shapes/018349-firey-orange-jelly-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```